# Purpose of MSFT DLL Import Libraries

Tags: windows, dll

I've read [Raymond Chen's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091013-00/?p=16403) on the subject, and am still unsure why import libraries are needed.

He states:

> *By convention, the standardized name is the undecorated name, and these undecorated names follow Win32 ABI rules (not C++ rules or Delphi rules or anything else). The job of the import library is to bridge the gap between the decorated name imported by the compiler and the undecorated name exported by the DLL. Think of it as a thunk library. Why doesn’t the linker auto-generate these thunks? Because under the classical model, linkers do not generate code. -Raymond*

AFAIK, all the import libraries did was

1. Provide link-time verification that the imported symbols are actually exported by some DLL
2. Fill in information in some table in the .exe about where to locate the corresponding DLL, and which symbols in the IAT need to be filled in? (Not sure how it does this)

But apparently there are actual stubs that are linked in? What do these stubs do?

Comment: Raymond's blog post is colored by him working on Windows 95, the last OS where thunks still made sense.  They bridged the gap between a 32-bit OS and legacy 16-bit code.  They stopped being relevant 20 years ago.  The analogy isn't very good either, the import library simply provides the DLL name and the actual name and ordinal of the exported functions.  Details that are not otherwise available to the compiler and linker.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the response. So thunks are no longer used then? Clearly the compiler doesn't care about any of this - but could the linker not get this information from the DLL itself?

Comment: That would only be possible if the IAT of the DLL contains both the decorated and the undecorated name.  It doesn't.  The import library does.

Comment: @HansPassant So why not just decorate the name in the DLL? C++ specific, how does the DLL expose undecorated names for overloaded functions?

Comment: It does not stop you from doing that, renaming the exported function is fairly unpleasant *extra* work.  The larger point of a DLL is to make code available to any language.  Most acutely obvious for an operating system DLL.  Name decoration is a language implementation detail, as noted by Raymond.

Comment: If there was no such thing as import libraries, and the DLL you wanted to link to didn't exist on your build machine, how would the build work?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I mean, I guess you cant build it then. But having the DLL on the build machine seems just as easy as the import library..

Comment: @Hans I see. Last question (thank you for your time and patience). Just to clarify what I was asking - there has to be *some* form of decoration when exporting overloaded C++ functions, no? The DLL can't list "foo" as an export symbol multiple times for foo(int), foo(float).

Comment: Sure, name mangling in C++ exists to keep using the linker of old.  If you want to make those overloads available to other C++ code then you have to keep it mangled.  There is no decent way to interop with C++, there is no ABI, so only the exact same compiler using the exact same compile options can use the DLL.  So mangling isn't an issue at all.

Comment: @anon: the import library is much smaller than the DLL it references.  That doesn't matter *quite* so much as it used to, but even these days if you're using SSD you want to save what space you can.  And when you're dealing with a commercial product the import library is typically available free of charge (in the case of Windows, you don't even need to register to download the SDK) but if you had to use the DLL you'd probably need to pay for an additional license for your build machine. :-)